# Airflow run task in a loop for each batch

Tags: airflow

I need to process multiple batches of rows from a file with each batch at a time. I was originally imagining Task-A splitting the file into x batches. Submit each batch to Task-B so B can process incoming batch (calling another REST end point). I was wondering if there is a way for a task (A) to call another task (B) in a loop as we construct each batch of rows sequentially? So B can process that batch.

If not, do you have a suggestion for a better way to design this batch processing system? One of the requirements is the ability to stop/start this file processing in flight and ability to run multiple files at the same time.

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code to make your question more clear?

Comment: Hey Mahsa, I dont have code right now. But I want to process a file in batches. So I want first 100 rows transformed in 1 task and then next task to process. Once thats done in a sequence transform and process next 100, etc. Which means I need to do this in a loop of 100 rows in each iteration. Is that possible?